# How to get dynamic table(contains table data) value on button click event in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a PHP code in which when page is run it will display dynamic records with an option of Update button. Now the problem is that it is generated dynamically, so how do I get particular COLUMN value of table record when a button is clicked?
[image]

Comment: Usually you just use an image or a link to delete or edit, then it points to the script that handles the operation with something like pagethatdeletes.php?id=<?php echo $yourid; ?> or pagethatedits.php?id=<?php echo $yourid; ?>

Comment: but how to do? I want that when I click on second record's Deactivate It button, it should delete that record, but How can I get that second record's ID? It's dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PHP to create table**

```
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";

    while( ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)))
    {
        echo "<td>".$row['no']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['notify']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['date']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['url']."</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='button' name='update' onClick='updateRecord(this)' id='update' value='".$row['id']."'></td>";
    }

    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
```

**JavaScript to update record**

```
function updateRecord(id)
{
    var recordId = id.value;
     ...Update record through ajax call...
     ...Update record through form submit...

}
```

**Update record through ajax call**

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'update.php',
        method: 'GET',
        data: 'userID=' + recordId,
        success: function(new_data){
             $(popID).html(new_data);
              $(popID).dialog();
              alert('Load was performed.');
        }
    });
```